# what does $data and $root mean in the following context

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application

I am following the tutorials at knockoutjs website. This is a code from that.

**view**

```
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
               click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>
```

**viewmodel**

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
     self.goToFolder = function(folder) { self.chosenFolderId(folder); };
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

what is $data and $root? where are they defined (where do they come from)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using a `foreach` binding, the binding-scope inside that block is the actual item you're iterating on. But sometimes you need to 'escape' that scope and get a reference to some property / method that is outside that scope.

- Use `$root` to access the root view-model
- Use `$parent` to access the object that is parent to the current scope

Also, you need to use `$data` to refer to the current item in the `foreach` loop. For example:

```
var vm = {
    arr: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
};

<div data-bind="foreach: arr">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: Great explanation! I wonder, if this could be found anywhere in the official KO documentation?